# JavaFX - Getting coordinates of objects of a webpage

Tags: webview, browser, coordinates, javafx

I'm currently working on my project using JavaFX WebEngine/WebView.
I have been trying to solve the problem that I'm currently facing, but I got stuck.

The problem is to find out if it is possible to
1. get coordinates of objects (hyperlinks, images, buttons etc) of a web page 
2. distinguish between selected objects (hyperlinks, images, buttons etc)

If possible, could you tell me how it can be done?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please explain the "coordinates of objects". If you are mentioning the location of the object in a page (ie. DOM hierarchy location) then since the `WebEngine` is like a web browser, you can manipulate the loaded HTML DOM object through the javascript and maybe better through javascipt framework like a JQuery. Just search the net "jquery" + "questions you asked".